# Android how to use "&" in the application Title name, i.e. in the xml file

Tags: android, html, xml

I wish to put my application title as Love & Hatred

I have my xml file from where i reference the Application title.
as this

```
<string name="app_name">Love &amp; Hatred</string>
```

I realized that simply providing "&" gives a compiler error, thus i added `&amp;` but still when i Run the application in the Device i just See the Title as

```
Love &
```

The rest of the part i.e. Hatred is missing.
Any clues anyone?

Comment: Ok, I realized that the Title was too long for the Launcher to display, but this brings me to another Question, How can i make the Application Icon Title Marquee(able).?

Comment: First of all, it's better to ask it as another question. by `Application Icon Title` you mean the application name displayed below the application icon in launcher? If so, you can't. text size, icon size, etc. are related to the launcher app, you can't change it from your application.

Comment: Yes Fardjad, I tried making a new question but my REPUTATION doesn't permit me for next 20 Mins to put another question on board, thanks for the prompt replies guys, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML parser is allowed to split a text node and deliver it to the application in several pieces, and it's common practice for parsers to use this flexibility to split the text at special characters like ampersand. The application needs to be written to buffer up the several pieces of text and concatenate them; it if doesn't, that's a bug in the application.

Comment: Understood and resolved thanks a lot, i appreciate the knowledge shared